# create EntityManager from EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get an instance of jpa `EntityManager` in a servlet as follows

```
ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory)context.getBean("entityManagerFactory");
EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
```

My question is , is it an efficient way to get an EntityManager instance inside a servlet get service method. Also should we close `EntityManagerFactory`/`EntityManager` explicitly in the above approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using spring, ideally you should use another layer (DAO for example) where you can have

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

And spring will take care of that.

If you really need that access in a servlet, rather than in a spring-mvc `@Controller`, then get the service/dao bean from the application context and use the above construct there. And if for some weird reason you should manually handle the entity manager - yes, you have to `.close()` it.

Comment: Spring doesn't take care. Maybe in spring 7.0 in 2021 it will be finally working. :-(